# gettin null value from checkbox in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a `form` and inside I have a `table` and each row I have `checkbox`

like this: `<input type="checkbox" name="register[]" value="123-3-158-855">`

When I click on the submit button to send to `controller`, return only NULL values from checkbox

```
public function update_rows()
{
    $data= $this->input->post('register');
    var_dump($data);
}
```

What's the problem? I can't see.

Edit: I found the problem, I'm using `datatable` in my table and when I removed works fine, but why???

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand that if a checkbox is unchecked when its form is submitted, there is no value submitted to the server to represent its unchecked state (e.g. value=unchecked); the value is not submitted to the server at all. In other words, when not checked then `$this->input->post('register');` will return NULL.

In the case of a field name array i.e. `name="register[]"` only the values for the checked boxes will be in the array.

Comment: Thank you. I tried with all checked and return null. The problem is in the `datatable` plugin